# Laravel protect form hidden fields and url

Tags: php, forms, security, laravel, laravel-4

I have an edit made with blade to edit a resource, like this:

```
{{Form::model( $post ,['action'=> ['PostController@update', 'id' => $post->id], 'method' => 'post'])}}
```

Which generates a form with action

```
http://example.com/posts/edit/123
```

And my fields, having text and hidden inputs

Seeing this url, it's very easy for a bad-intentioned user to update other posts.

How can I protect the route to make it fail if the id is manipulated with the inspector? Is there any built-in wat to tokenize the id to make sure it matches? Can this also de applied to all the hidden inputs?

Thanks

EDIT:

An example on my hidden fields usage:
My posts are generally questions and answers, when an user tries to add an answer to a question, I set question_id as a hidden field, and I want to check it is not manipulated.

Comment: Do you mean this: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#csrf-protection?

Comment: Instead of trying to protect your URLs you should protect your data by authentication and authorization. Instead of relying on the user not knowing the right URL you should check for a login and (if needed) user permissions

Comment: I already do this $this->abortIfLoggedUserCantEdit( $post->user->id ); I just want a more generic feature.

Comment: I've looked at CSRF protection, but it stores a token in session and checks that it is in the submitted form, not if the html has been manipulated

Comment: You're probably looking for an ACL system like [Sentry](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry) or [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)

Comment: I'm using jacopo/laravel-authentication-acl, but a logged user can also be a bad-intentioned user.

Comment: Well you cannot always defend yourself against that, **but** you can do this: set a Session variable equal to the model's ID when the `edit` method is requested, then pull that variable from session when the form is submitted, `find()` the model with that id and update it. This way you will not even need to keep the ID in the URL or in a hidden field. Sounds like a good exercise for a Middleware!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Limonte's answer is correct to secure the ability to edit other peoples posts - and you should always do that. To answer the second half of your question:

> I set question_id as a hidden field, and I want to check it is not manipulated.

The problem is that you can **never** trust the data supplied by a client to your system. You must **always** assume it has been tampered with.

One option to help *minimize* the risk is you can use the [encryption service by Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/encryption) to do this:

```
{{ Form::hidden('question_id', Crypt::encrypt($question_id)) }}
```

Then in your controller

```
$question_id = Crypt::decrypt(Input::get('question_id'));
```

Just make sure you've set a random application encryption key in your `app.php` config file

Comment: I'll add an encrypted route_id to all my forms, and put a filter to check it on every request.

Comment: @Laurence , I'm also trying to realize this in my project, but after a little bit thinking, i went to that, It's not so good to encrypt just id field. Because, I can go to users with id X, check encrypted id in form, and after that go to user roles, and place the same encrypted id X, and it will be valid, if role with id X exists. To resolve this, there should be unique id per model, so we can just add in encryption before id field model name or database table name.

Comment: How to you use the Crypt::encrypt in an HTML <form> instead of using {{ Form }} ?

Answer (score 3):

To protect route you should check permission in `PostController@update`.

In the method beginning check if user can edit given post:

```php
public function update($postId)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($postId);

    if ($post->user_id !== Auth::id()) {
        abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
    }

    // validate, update record, etc.
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this, but I want a generic way to do this for all my edit routes, also I can't protect hidden fields this way

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to do this for all your edit routes.  You could use a filter but you will have other routes where the parameters are named differently and you'd be working with different relationships.  You'd end up having 1 filter for each controller.

Comment: Is it `Auth::id()` or `Auth::user()->id`?

Comment: I think a hidden input in the form with the id hashed, and checking if the id from the route and the hashed one match may work

Comment: it's ``Auth::id()``, https://github.com/illuminate/auth/blob/master/Guard.php#L176

Comment: @limonte - lol - cool - i didnt know that existed. Learn something new every day!